# How To: Separate curl var_dump output into different variables?

Tags: php, xml, curl

In here i want to separate the string output into three different variables. Request is in XML. Currently I am getting output as string in one line with some spaces. But i want the output to be separated.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
$api_entry_point = "https://api-sandbox.instantmobilizer.com/v1";

$user = "abcde";
$pass = "abcde12345";
$url = $api_entry_point."/create_site";

$xml= "<?xml version='1.0'?>

<request>
    <subscription>
        <end_date>+1 month</end_date>
        <billing_cycle>FT</billing_cycle>
        <service_level>1</service_level>
        <promotion_code>free_trial:armo</promotion_code>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <contract_type>FT</contract_type>
        <spare_1/>
        <spare_2/>
        <sub_reseller_id>yoyo</sub_reseller_id>
        <reseller_reference>111199999</reseller_reference>
        <mapping>
            <source_domain>testingnet.com</source_domain>
            <mobile_domain>testingvyoyo.net</mobile_domain>
            <properties />
            <aliases />
        </mapping>
    </subscription>
</request>";


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$user}:{$pass}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);

/*echo '<pre>'.var_dump($output).'</pre>';*/

?>
```

Current Output is

```
string(184) " ok 985161e2980c65fa 2016-03-18 "
```

Comment: what is current and expected output? Post same in question

Comment: do not use `var_dump` ,use `echo` instead.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta i have update the current output.please have a look.

Comment: try `$var = explode(' ', trim($output)); print_r($var)`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta thanks this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$var = explode(' ', trim($output));
echo $var[0].;

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you retrieve, you could simply find the pattern of your datas and use `explode` or `regex`. If you retrieve XML you can also use `SimpleXMLParser`.